# Checking if rental vehicle is available

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a vehicle renting platform, but i need to see which cars  are available based on date.

The tables look like the following

`Reservations (id, user_id, vehicle_id, pickup_time, dropoff_time)`

`Vehicle (id, etc (the rest of the columns do not really matter))`

I've tried many stuff but i keep retrieving booked cars.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint  `LEFT JOIN WHERE ... IS NULL`   `NOT IN()`  and  `NOT EXISTS()`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select v.*
from vehicle v
where not exists (select 1
                  from reservations r
                  where r.vehicle_id = v.id and
                        @date <= r.dropoff_time and
                        @date >= r.pickup_time
                 );
```

Notes:

- `@date` is the time you want to check.
- Usually, rentals are for a period, so normally there would be two times.  But your question is explicitly about a single date.  Ask another question if this is not quite what you intended to ask.
- Usually, there is a lag between the drop off and the next pick up, for maintenance purposes.

Comment: Woah, thanks! Also thanks for the quick answer @Gordon . Yeah you are right it was meant for two dates. dropoff and pickup. How would i go on doing that any tips or something?